# Using Vimperator with Programmer Dvorak

Tags: vimperator, dvorak, shift

In Programmer Dvorak layout keyboard (image), numbers are on top of the row, you have to press Shift to add a number. Do you have any ideas not to use Shift when on Hint mode of Vimperator? (Others keys still keep normal.)

[image]

Comment: Well, now I move to VimFx. The promblem is somewhat solved.

Comment: I am so used to this keyboard I never thought about changing that… but what about maping every symbol with a number ? And what are the benefits of VimFx please ?

Comment: If you mapping symbols to numbers, then some symbols will not work, such as `+` for zoom in or `]` to go to next page. 
In VimFx, you don't need to hit numbers to go to the hints, you hit characters, see [this](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/6695517/3096363/2aec9a0a-e5d3-11e3-9f30-8962031c58b3.png)

Comment: Slightly of topic, but I would suggest using pentadactyl rather than vimperator, albeit you will have to get the source and compile it yourself, but that's a painless process

Comment: @JohnC why would you suggest that?

Comment: @Ooker, Pentadactyl just  feels a lot less buggy than Vimperator, or at least that's what I felt when I switched...

Answer (score 2):

I use a modified `hintchars` instead of `01233456789` to match the dvorak home row:

```
set hintchars=aoeuidhtns
```

Then if you're in quickhint mode and you want to switch to searching by link text, press `\` (default `mapleader`).